# When is $li(x)$ a better estimate than $li(x) - (1/2) li(\sqrt{x})$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

We know that [Skewes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number) number is the smallest integer $x$ such that,

$$\pi(x) > \operatorname{li}(x)$$

where $\pi(x)$ is the *prime counting function* and $\operatorname{li}(x)$ is the *logarithmic integral function*.

The same Wikipedia article explains that the current best estimate is around $1.39716 \times 10^{316}$ and that $\pi(x) - \operatorname{li}(x)$ switches signs infinitely often.

It is sometimes suggested that $\operatorname{li}(x) - \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{li}(\sqrt{x})$ is a better estimate for $\pi(x)$.  But given the above, this can’t always be true although it is certainly true for small $x$.

What is a good estimate for the smallest $x$ for which

$$|\operatorname{li}(x) - \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{li}(\sqrt{x}) - \pi(x)| > | \operatorname{li}(x) - \pi(x) |\;?$$

Comment: Interesting (+1) , although li(x) is (assuming the Riemann hypothesis) already an excellent approximation. I also think that Dusart's bounds are sharp enough for most purposes. Nevertheless, I am curious whether someone can answer this question.

Comment: It's known from Littlewood that $|\pi(x)-\operatorname{li}(x)|>x^{1/2}\log\log\log x/\log x$ for infinitely many $x$.

Answer (score 1):

By the research following Littlewood and Skewes, it's known to be less than $e^{727.95133}$. But we can do better with some direct calculation!

Excluding $x\in[2,2.106472\ldots)$, the first example that I find is $x=30902129$. If I'm not mistaken this is the first crossover with $x\ge3.$

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: Just looping over primes. Naive calculations are easy enough with numbers this small.